How to stream/chunk data for an ODATA Service with Python
I have a Flask ODATA API service that is working, I can sucesfully import data to Excel or other platafroms that can import an ODATA Feed.
However I am currently migrating said API to Google Cloud Functions, but they have a limit of 32mb for HTTP/1 requests and responses.
I have been reading online documentation of different libraries as json-stream and flask Streaming Contents however I can't still understand how to partition or append the specific chunks to the response, and have the program (excel, powerbi, etc) understand to expect X amount of chunks
This is how I currently have it set it up:
    results = df.to_dict('records')
    results_dict = {}
    results_dict["@odata.context"] = f"{DOMAIN}odataservice/{category}/$metadata#{object_method}"
    results_dict["value"] = results
    response = jsonify(results_dict)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal"
    response.headers["OData-Version"] = "4.0"
    response.headers["Vary"] = "Accept-Encoding"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "-1"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    return response

any insight, explanation or help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance,

Based on this documentation on Cloud Functions Resource Limits:



Quota
Limit (1st gen)
Limit (2nd gen)




Max uncompressed HTTP request size
10MB
32MB


Max uncompressed HTTP response size
10MB
10MB for streaming responses. 32MB for non-streaming responses.



The regional scope is per project, and each project maintains its own limits. Also, there is no option to increase the quota.
I would suggest to check out the following in order to overcome the limit:

Bypass the Cloud Run 32mb Limit with Cloud Storage
How to overcome Cloud Run's 32MB request limit
Bypassing Cloud Run 32mb error via HTTP2 end to end solution

Please be advised that Cloud Functions 2nd gen is built on Cloud Run and Eventarc so that steps above should work similarly.
